# HTTP redirect to HTTPS Codeigniter deployed on Microsoft Azure

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, https, web-config

Hi I am trying to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS for my codeigniter app hosted on Microsoft Azure. I have placed the following code in my web.config file but the redirect does not seem to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
           <rules>
            <!-- BEGIN rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
             <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
               <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
               <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
             </rule>
             <!-- END rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
            <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
             </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is there another file I need to config as well? I've tried changing my .htaccess file as well as creating a hook.

Would love to know why the HTTPS redirect is not working in my web.config file and if there are any other steps I need to take for it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your `web.config` file for the CodeIgniter app and the redirect action worked properly.

Here the folder structure:
[image]

So your config file is fine actually. Please make sure that the web.config file is under the `/wwwroot` directory.

Alternatively, you can install the site extension called `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` to achieve this through Kudu Site Extensions which could be accessed via `https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions#gallery`.

Step by Step

1. In search box enter "*redirect*", then click **Search** button.
   [image]
2. Select `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` and click **ADD** button.
3. Then the dialog will be opened, click **Install** button.
4. To make it available by clicking **Restart Site** button.